# How to interpolate variables into 'then' expressions

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-el

I'm trying to do create a thymeleaf fragment that behaves like the following:

```html
<section th:fragment="alert(type)" th:class="${type ? 'alert-' + type : ''}"></section>
```

```html
<div th:replace="alert(info)"></div>
```

```html
<section class="alert-info"></section>
```

I've tried interpolation |alert-${type}|, and concatenation 'alert-' + type, but I can't get it working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Thymeleaf fragment, add a null check:

```
<section th:fragment="alert(type)" 
         th:class="${type != null ? 'alert-' + type : ''}">
</section>
```

Optionally, I prefer to put literals into single quotes, just for clarity. And when passing values to fragments, I also prefer to use the parameter names (again, this is optional).

In the following examples, the `alert_fragment.html` is my test fragment.

```
<div th:replace="alert_fragment.html :: alert(type='info')"></div>
```

And for the null case:

```
<div th:replace="alert_fragment.html :: alert(type=null)"></div>
```

If you are passing the type value from the server, then it would be something like this, of course:

```
<div th:replace="alert_fragment.html :: alert(type=${info})"></div>
```

The resulting HTML:

```
<body>
    <section class="alert-info"></section>
    <section></section>
</body>
```

**Update**

If the alert type will never be null, then you can simplify the fragment to this:

```
<section th:fragment="alert(type)" th:class="'alert-' + ${type}"></section>
```

Comment: fantastic :). Thanks! As an aside, in my testing I was always providing a value, why is the null check necessary even if there is a value?

Comment: I'll update the answer and add a note about that - you can simplify the code.